# Ring in which $x^n-x$ is central for every $x$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings, local-rings

Let $R$ be a ring , $n \gt 1$, such that for all $x \in R$: $x^n-x \in Z(R)$, the center of $R$. Does it follow that $R$ is commutative?

For $n=2,3$ this is pretty straightforward to prove. But what about higher powers? This is a generalization of Nathan Jacobson's theorem that if $x^n=x$ for all $x \in R$, then $R$ is commutative.

Comment: I guess you're implicitly assuming that $R$ is associative (there is no universal convention on this). Are you assuming that $R$ is unital (the condition doesn't pass to the unitalization immediately).

Comment: Associativity yes, but not necessarily unital!

Comment: Is there something particular with this polynomial $x^n-x$? What if it is replaced with another monic polynomial of degree $\ge 2$ (with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}$ or $R$, I'm not sure).

Comment: There are also links/posts about this on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3472649/29335

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks!! And Ycor: would the general question be the study of rings obeying a polynomial identity (P.I. Rings)?

Comment: You might be interested in this survey: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2006.07.001

Comment: Thanks Emil, very nice reference and piece to read!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Herstein, "A generalization of a theorem of Jacobson"  Amer. J. Math. 73 (1951), 756–762 proves this. Also part III,  Amer. J. Math. 75 (1953), 105–111 proves something a bit more general. Namely, the hypothesis can be weakened to $\forall x\ \exists\,n>1\ \cdots$

Comment: Thanks Dave, will check out these papers! Appreciated!

Comment: Let's thank JSTOR for taking money out of [this 72-year-old paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372114) (part III [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372619)).

Comment: @Ycor Yes exactly I looked it up at JSTOR! I am very grateful .. And the Part III is very interesting indeed in the sense that $n \gt 1$ can be depend on $x$ so to speak. Quite unexpected ...

Comment: @NickyHekster Well, in the original theorem of Jacobson, $n$ also can depend on $x$, so that’s not surprising.

Comment: There's also a nice survey paper by James Pinter-Lucke, "Commutativity conditions for rings: 1950-2005".

Comment: Dave thanks, see the comments/link of Emil above. That is the paper.

Comment: Indeed. I hadn't seen that comment.